# How to show a downloadable link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to show a downloadable link on my MVC application's View using ActionLink:

```
<div>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Test","Download","Admin") %>
</div>

public ActionResult Download()
{   
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {        
        FileName = "Download Me", 
        Inline = false, 
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    byte[] csvBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello");
    return File(csvBytes, "csv","DownloadMe.csv");
}
```

The link shows up on the UI but when I click on it, I get an "Endpoint not found" error.
I am new to MVC and trying this out for the first time. Can someone please help.

Comment: Is your `Download` method in a controller named `Admin`? What is the exact error message? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Yes and Yes. I am using FF. Error: Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few issues with the controller method:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] csvBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello");
    return File(csvBytes, "text/csv","DownloadMe.csv");
}
```

1. You want to return a `FileResult`, not an `ActionResult`.
2. The mime type is `text/csv` rather than just `csv`.
3. I don't think the content disposition is required, but I would take it out until you get it working and then add it back later if necessary.

Comment: I used the above controller. But get the same error message "Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."

Comment: Sounds like you might have some routing issues going on. Can you hit the URL by typing it directly into the browser?

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly when I type the URL directly on the browser

Comment: So when you inspect the generated action link in the page source, is the URL different?

Comment: You are right. It is showing: <a href="/AccountService?action=Download&amp;controller=Admin">Test</a>